# I want to image from another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic/angular. In my edit profile page(different page), I can change the profile pic and it should reflect the same in main profile page(another page), these two pages are different.

HTML:

```
<ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-avatar class="ion-align-self-left" id="pic" (click)="change()">
        <img src="{{myphoto}}">
    </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

TS:

```
   export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
   myphoto:any;

  constructor(private camera: Camera) {
    this.myphoto = '/assets/img/DP.svg';
   this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
     }
   ngOnInit() {
  }
 take(){
     this.ishide =true;
    this.hide_input =false;
    const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 70,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

   this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
    // If it's base64:
   this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
   }, (err) => {
   // Handle error
   });
   }
    get() {
   this.ishide =true;
   this.hide_input =false;
    const options: CameraOptions = {
     quality: 70,
     destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
     sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
     saveToPhotoAlbum:false
      }
      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64:
     this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
     });
      }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the same service in both modules by importing it with "constructor injection"

```
constructor(private myProfileService: ProfileService) {  }
```

Then just bind to a property getting its value from the service.

Comment: The answer from "SiddAjmera" is the perfect answer
You create the SharedService to store your data in

You inject it in the constructor of your 2 modules
constructor(
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

You observe the data from your service in those modules
ngOnInit() {
    this.profilePicture$ = this.sharedService.profilePicture$;
  }

In html you look at the data from it 
-$ is a naming convention for obserable param
-async pipe is added as this is a async operation
<img [src]="profilePicture$ | async"> 

So make sure to check his answer

Comment: The only thing missing in his example is the need to provide the service in 'app.module.ts' 

`@NgModule({ providers: [ SharedService ] })`

Answer (score 0):

You need some global state, that would store the path/base64 of the avatar image.

Tipically, you would get the image everytime the component (page) is inited and assign the path/base64 to some variable.

I would use a global service or maybe avatar service that would store the avatar data via Subject/BehaviourSubject. You can find more about them [here](https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/)

You would subscribe to changes or get the new image from the service in the component whenever the page is inited (ngOnInit).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SharedService`. Expose a public `Observable` and a method to set the value of that using a private `BehaviorSubject`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private profilePicture: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>( 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/siddajmera-dev.appspot.com/o/Avatar.jpg?alt=media&token=ba992ea4-3198-4971-b4ee-5454ec2b3cbd');
  public profilePicture$: Observable<string> = this.profilePicture.asObservable();

  setProfilePicture(newProfilePicture: string) {
    this.profilePicture.next(newProfilePicture);
  }
}
```

Inject this service in the Pages where you want to change the Profile Picture and set it:

Where you want to display:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { SharedService } from '../../app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  profilePicture$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profilePicture$ = this.sharedService.profilePicture$;
  }

}
```

And in the Template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Main Profile Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-avatar class="ion-align-self-left" id="pic">
            <img [src]="profilePicture$ | async">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Where you want to set it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { SharedService } from '../../app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  profilePicutre$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profilePicutre$ = this.sharedService.profilePicture$;
  }

  change() {
    this.sharedService.setProfilePicture(`https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1116889337075920898/foGk0y53_400x400.jpg`);
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Edit Profile Page
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-avatar class="ion-align-self-left" id="pic" (click)="change()">
            <img [src]="profilePicutre$ | async">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And in 'app.module.ts' provide the SharedService

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomePage,
        Aboutpage
    ],
    providers: [ SharedService ] 
})
```

---

> PS: I'm not using the Camera API or anything in the example. But even if you're using that to get the image updated, this is how you'd do it. Using a `SharedService`.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/profile-picture-change-shared-service?file=pages/home/home.html) for your ref.

Comment: getting errors when I try to integrate your approach into my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself by simply using localstorage and ongoing back that current page will refresh and changes which are made in the edit_profile page will get affected in the profile page.

edit_profile.ts

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
myphoto: any = "/assets/img/DP.svg";
picture: any;

constructor(
private camera: Camera,
private statusBar: StatusBar,
private router: Router
) {
this.picture = localStorage.getItem("pic");

this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#ffffff");
}
back() {
 this.router.navigateByUrl("/profile");
  }
take() {
this.ishide = true;
this.hide_input = false;
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 70,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
};

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
    imageData => {
    // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
    // If it's base64:
    this.myphoto = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    localStorage.setItem("pic", this.myphoto);
    this.picture = localStorage.getItem("pic");
    },
     err => {
    // Handle error
   }
   );
   }

  get() {
 this.ishide = true;
 this.hide_input = false;
  const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 70,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };
```

edit_profile.html

```html
<img src="{{picture}}">
```

profile.ts

```
export class MainProfilePage implements OnInit {
 picc: any;

  ionViewWillEnter() {
this.picc = localStorage.getItem("pic");
console.log("works");
```

}

profile.html

```html
<img src="{{picc}}">
```